# Error "Android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExeption" in login android

Tags: android

I tried connection from android application to the mysql database with the IP, after I try running the my apps I click the login button to go to the next page but error show message "unfortunately has stopped"..

I do not know what is wrong, maybe I think the in my class json parse.

This is class > JSON 
Parser.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Comment: read this http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html

Comment: You should perform all this from AsyncTask, Not activity.

Comment: Httpcalls and other long running operations must not be performed on the main UI thread,try to use AsyncTask instead

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when you are trying to make a network operation on his main thread..

Run your code in an `AsyncTask` or create a different `Thread`

and don't forget to add the internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```